# Apply postcode API call to each row in dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

In the below code block, I have a dataframe, `geo`, which I want to iterate over to get the easting, northing, longitude and latitude for each UK postcode in `geo`.  I've written a function to call the API and another to return the four variables.

I've tested the `get_data` call with a postcode to prove it works (this is a public API anyone can use):

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd

geo = spark.table('property_address').toPandas()


def call_api(url: str) -> dict:
  postcode_response =requests.get(url)
  return postcode_response.json()

def get_data(postcode):

  url = f"http://api.getthedata.com/postcode/{postcode}"
  
  req = r.get(url)
  

  results = req.json()['data']
  easting = results['easting']
  northing = results['northing']
  latitude = results['latitude']
  longitude = results ['longitude']
  
  return easting ,northing,latitude, longitude

get_data('SW1A 1AA')
```

which returns:

```
Out[108]: (529090, 179645, '51.501009', '-0.141588')
```

Want I want to do is run that for each row in `geo` and return it as a dataset.  My research has led me to `apply`, and I've based my attempt on [this guide](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/api-calls-pandas-dataframe-pd-apply).

I'm trying to pass a column called `property_postcode` in `geo` and iterate each row to return the values, here's my attempt:

```
def get_columns(row):
  column_name = 'property_postcode'
  api_param = row[column_name]
  easting,northing,latitude,longitude = get_data(api_param)
  row['east'] = easting
  row['north'] = northing
  row['lat'] = latitude
  row['long'] = longitude
  return row

geo= geo.apply(get_columns, axis=1)

display(geo)
```

The error I get is

```
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
```

Doesn't tell me a huge amount.  Looking for assistance\pointers.

Comment: Are you looking for Pandas solution or PySpark solution?

Comment: Either, I'm guessing PySpark might have a little more oomph behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the values for the east, north, lat and long columns in the function return them from the function.

```py
from numpy import result_type
import requests
import pandas as pd

# geo = spark.table('property_address').toPandas()


def call_api(url: str) -> dict:
    postcode_response = requests.get(url)
    return postcode_response.json()


def get_data(postcode):
    url = f"http://api.getthedata.com/postcode/{postcode}"
    req = requests.get(url)

    if req.json()["status"] == "match":
        results = req.json()["data"]
        easting = results.get("easting")
        northing = results.get("northing")
        latitude = results.get("latitude")
        longitude = results.get("longitude")
    else:
        easting = None
        northing = None
        latitude = None
        longitude = None

    return easting, northing, latitude, longitude


def get_columns(code):
    api_param = code
    return get_data(api_param)


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "property_postcode": [
            "BE21 6NZ",
            "SW1A 1AA",
            "W1A 1AA",
            "DE21",
            "B31",
            "ST16 2NY",
            "S65 1EN",
        ]
    }
)

df[["east", "north", "lat", "long"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: get_columns(row["property_postcode"]), axis=1, result_type="expand"
)

print(df)
```

| property_postcode | east | north | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BE21 6NZ | NaN | NaN | None | None |
| SW1A 1AA | 529090 | 179645 | 51.501009 | -0.141588 |
| W1A 1AA | 528887 | 181593 | 51.518561 | -0.143799 |
| DE21 | NaN | NaN | None | None |
| B31 | NaN | NaN | None | None |
| ST16 2NY | 391913 | 323540 | 52.809346 | -2.121413 |
| S65 1EN | 444830 | 394082 | 53.44163 | -1.326573 |

Comment: Looks great, will review and come back to you tomorrow.  Massive thanks.

Comment: Thanks mate, worked, I needed to create a subset of my `geo` dataset to only have property postcodes and then merge it back in.  There are some postcodes that are invalid for data quality reasons which can cause this to fail, is there anything that can be done to skip/ignore/return null for those rows whilst running the apply?  Otherwise, I'll just have to run DQ in preceding scripts.

Comment: I actually experienced that problem when testing the code with some dummy data. I didn't investigate it further but you could probably do something in the get_data function. For example, return NA for easting, northern etc. for an invalid postcode. Could you post some example data with a mix of valid/invalid postcodes?

Comment: An invalid would "DE21 6"  or "B31", valid ones are "ST16 2NY" or "S65 1EN"

Comment: I've updated the answer to return NaN/None for easting/northing etc for invalid postcodes.

Comment: Thanks again, I had to make one final tweak because the response didn't always contain the `data` key (it would return an `error` key instead if it couldn't find the postcode, example is "BE21 6NZ" ) so `get_data` has an if statement which checks to see if the response string has it in it, otherwise it sets the variables to None.  Would you mind if I edited your post with it? Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated the code to, hopefully, handle the situation when a matching postcode isn't found.

Comment: Yeh that's broadly what I did, I looked at the response as a string and looked for "'data':" Thanks.

Comment: I was originally going to use the if statement I added but found that even for something like 'B31' there was a match, and there was a data element in the JSON. The difference was in what was in that data element.